# WordPress Code Snippet to count total posts by author

Tags: customization

I want to run a WordPress code Snippet that can show total posts by author.
something like this:

author1: 37 posts
author2: 12 posts
author3: 43 posts

is possible this?.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to get all users calling `get_users()` function. Then you can use `count_user_posts()` to display post count for a user.

Try below code.

```
    <?php
    $blogusers = get_users();
    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        echo 'Number of posts published by '.esc_html($user->display_name).': ' . count_user_posts( esc_html($user->id) ).'</br>';
    } 
    ?>
```

**Update : You can easily use `wp_list_authors()` function also.**

```
<?php wp_list_authors('show_fullname=1&optioncount=1&orderby=post_count&order=DESC'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :). How can I call to the get_users() function into the code snippet?. I'm not sure abou.t how to do all at the sime time

Comment: @Hueznar I updated the answer. You can  use `wp_list_authors()` function also. And If you check my first code snippets I have already added the `get_users()` part.

Comment: OK now the code it works, but returns 0 posts in all authors posts :?

Comment: For 1st code snippet or 2nd code snippet?

Comment: for the first one.

Comment: @Hueznar I found a mistake in my code. I updated the first one. Please try it again and let me know.

Comment: still returns me 0 fo each user

Comment: @Hueznar I tested the code. It worked fine with my sites.

Comment: I'm executing this into code snippets utility of my blog insidde a manageWP account: https://snag.gy/UngSdW.jpg

Comment: I don't know what is the reason for not working it for you. You may have to ask it from support staff of Manage WP. Or just try it inside WordPress like site specific plugin or functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Yaa I can help you just rectify the previous code a little bit... need some small change.

```
count_user_posts( esc_html( $user->ID ) )
```

Please try this. You'll get the required results. Thanks.

Comment: I did modifications, but still I'm getting 0 posts in all users. 

Current code I have is this:

`<?php
    $blogusers = get_users();
    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
        echo 'Number of posts published by '.esc_html($user->display_name).': ' . count_user_posts( esc_html( $user->ID ) ).'</br>';
    } 
?>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your case get_users() is not working that means this function is not being called at all & not returning the existing data....whereas it's working perfect for us.

get_users() is one of the WordPress default functions & I also have confusions that where are you just trying to execute this code ??

You need to execute this code on respective script into wp-content/themes/ folder . Plz let me know your feedback.

Comment: I'm executing this code with manageWP app that is a WP solution to manage multiple WP in one site. ManageWP has a tool called "Code Snippets" that can be run from its enviroment and I pasted code provided by "Ranuka" inside of this web app. Here you can see a screenshot about how I'm doing this: https://snag.gy/UngSdW.jpg .I'm doing this because I own multiple WP sites and want to know how many posts have been published by my users in each blog. ManageWP allow me to launch code snippets in multiple blogs at same time, for that reason I'm looking for a "magical" code that works for this. Thanks

Comment: I understand I'm executing this code outside WP path you said, so I need some solution to have same results with some "magic" code snippet, if possible

Comment: Thanks for the required brief @Hueznar . You should contact ManageWP team immediately for your requirement, as it's a special case. They will definitely have a provision to show no of blogs posted by the respective admins on ManageWP admin panel or it will take some time for us to set up the required environment & to figure out the issue.